# Is there a Skype replacement voice app?

Tags: compatibility

Has anybody setup Raspberry Pi as cheap desktop PC for their family?

I would like to do that but first think I stumbled is Skype. My sister studies abroad so she and my mother talk a lot on Skype, and there is no Skype version for Raspberry Pi (arm cpu).

Is there any other VOIP app that works as great as Skype and is easy for parents to use?  Video is not a strict requirement but a nice to have feature...

There is some talk on Raspberry Pi forums that MAYBE Skype will be able to run someday, but not today - http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1891

Comment: Forget Skype, it's a broken insecure platform. IMO everyone should migrate to a better VOIP application anyway.

Comment: What about Google Voice?

Comment: @Jivings which VOIP application do you suggest? It should be easy enough for regular users to use, not us geeks, I need something that I can give to my parents and sister...

Comment: I agree that skype shouldn't be used, because it can't be maintained by the community. But as concerns running skype: can't we take the Skype for ARM for Android or Maemo, and tweak the environment in the Linux system on Raspeberry PI so that it runs. There must be Skype builds for Android and for Maemo/Meego/Tizen/whatever.

Comment: @imz It would need to be built for armv6. Not as simple as it sounds.

Comment: Googling "armv6" "skype" gives some results: http://devforum.skype.com/t5/Compiling-Runtimes/SkypeKit-doesn-t-work-on-ARMv6/td-p/14069 or http://devforum.skype.com/t5/Compiling-Runtimes/linux-armv6-skypekit-voicepcm-videortp-still-Status-is-Building/td-p/14241 . So, there is something. Not that I support this direction. We should better find a free software and build a community-supported service for this task.

Comment: I use UV4L and its Jitsi Meet plugin for VoIP with family

Answer (score 9):

After looking long and hard it looks like [Mumble](http://mumble.sourceforge.net/) is best replacement for Skype. It needs a server but it is much easier to configure than Asterisk.

Comment: Mumble (or [Murmur](http://mumble.sourceforge.net/Running_Murmur)) is a *great* service which is, in my opinion, better than Ventrilo, but is very similar.

Answer (score 3):

## Asterisk

Asterisk is an open source PBX.

Someone has a [blog](http://www.raspberry-asterisk.org/) with a Debian image on which Asterisk is installed. There is also some evidence on the [forums](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?p=70730#p70730) it is working.

Comment: Asterisk is an overkill for this situation, and I don't know of anybody hosting free asterisk service :(
It should be easy enough for regular users to use, not us geeks, I need something that I can give to my parents and sister...

Comment: Don't you just need a SIP trunk?

Comment: Since Skype was bought out by Microsoft, the Asterisk Skype gateway implementation has been stopped. But yes- using the likes of voipcheap is a great alternative to skype and you can use a SIP client on your smartphone to call the world at extrelly low cost.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [Linphone](https://www.linphone.org) may be worth consideration, especially as it is also a 
videophone, and is still actively maintained.

Answer (score -1):

I would use [UV4L](http://linux-projects.org) for two-way audio/video in the browser. [Screenshot 1](http://www.linux-projects.org/downloads/screenshots/webrtc-twoway.png). It works with Jitsi Meet too.

Comment: This is the best way for Rpi indeed

Comment: This answer is rather useless without any hints on how to set this up.